# How to access opendaylight API's

Tags: docker, rest, sdn, opendaylight

I am new to OpenDayLight I am having issues with calling API's in OpenDayLight

1. I installed the OpendayLight using Docker using this command
   docker pull opendaylight/opendaylight:0.18.0
2. Then stared opendaylight karaf container
3. Then Setup the AAA using this documentation           https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/aaa/en/latest/user-guide.html
4. I am able to access these AAA API's in the postman or curl
5. I used curl command to display to get all users and other curl command to manage AAA API'S
   curl --request GET 'http://localhost:8181/auth/v1/users' --header 'Authorization: Basic YWRtaW46YWRtaW4='
6. When I tried to access the API's in OVSDB I am not able to access them

   1. In the karaf CLI I installed OVSDB
      feature:install odl-ovsdb-southbound-impl-ui
   2. Then tried to access this API in postamn with basic authorisation
      http://<controller-ip>:8181/restconf/config/network-topology:network-topology/topology/ovsdb:1/

I followed this documentation https://docs.opendaylight.org/projects/ovsdb/en/latest/ovsdb-user-guide.html
I also not able to access any other API's rather than AAA API's I am not sure If I am missing something here. I did add the features in the karaf CLI.

Thank you so much for your help in advance.

http://<controller-ip>:8181/restconf/config/network-topology:network-topology/topology/ovsdb:1/
I am supposed to ge this result
`{   "topology": [     {       "topology-id": "ovsdb:1"     }   ] }` 
But getting this result instead
404 not found error
`<html>

Error 404 Not Found

### HTTP ERROR 404 Not Found

URI:/restconf/config/network-topology:network-topology/topology/ovsdb:1/
STATUS:404
MESSAGE:Not Found
SERVLET:default
`